# How to get the current seconds in the current month?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the current second in the current month, but I'm having trouble creating a simple function that does it.

My best guess involves using getTime() - the current milliseconds since January 1 1970 - and then subtracting X, where X is the number of milliseconds up to the end of the previous month.

Can you help me think of a better way to do this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime(),
      monthStart = new Date();

  monthStart.setDate(1);
  monthStart.setHours(0);
  monthStart.setMinutes(0);
  monthStart.setSeconds(0);
  monthStart.setMilliseconds(0);
  return Math.floor((now - monthStart.getTime()) / 1000);
}
```

Comment: `Date.now()` should do instead of `new Date().getTime()`, otherwise +1.

Comment: Thank you for that, very helpful to see the function all written out. Cheers,

Comment: I have no idea how I've missed out on Date.now(). Cheers @deceze!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Date instance and then call methods to set everything back to 00:00:00 on the first day of the month. Then you'd subtract that from the "now" timestamp.

The methods you'd call are `setDate(1)` to set the day-of-month back to the start of the month, and then `setHours()`, `setMinutes()`, `setSeconds()`, and `setMilliseconds()`, passing all those zero.

Timestamps (return values from `getTime()` are in milliseconds, so you'll divide your difference by 1000 to get the seconds into the month.

Comment: Cheers for that. Your explanation + wombleton's written function were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new date set to the first day of the month, like so:

```
var start = Date.parse("2010-11-01");
```

Then you can create a date for today:

```
var today = Date.now();
```

Then you just subtract them:

```
var seconds_in_month = today - start;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your solution just helped me with a more advanced version of the function I'm making. Cheers!